# No such file or directory despite using -I flag

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to run preprocessor and generate .i files using the following command 
(I based on http://jkorpela.fi/html/cpre.html) :

```
gcc -Irange/v3/action -x c -P -C -E range/v3/action.hpp
```

but I have error:

> range/v3/action.hpp:17:10: fatal error: range/v3/action/action.hpp: No such file or directory 
>    `#include <range/v3/action/action.hpp>`

The command is called from include directory. Directories tree is shown below:

```
-include
  -range
    -v3
      -action.hpp (file)
      -action (directory)
        -action.hpp
```

I've tried replace -I flag with other options, for example -Irange/**, but it did not work also.

I will be grateful for your solution or suggestion.

Comment: You've tagged this as both [tag:c] and [tag:c++], which is it? Why are you trying to include a C++ header while using the `-x c` option for C files? What is that command even supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

The path specified in `#include` is appended to the directory in `-I`. So it's looking for `range/v3/action/range/v3/action/action.hpp`. That's duplicating the directory path, because you have it in both `-I` and `#include`.

Either use `-I.` to start the search from the current directory, or use `#include <action.hpp>` to just search for the filename in the `-I` directory.